# How to run a node utility in a .cmd or .bat file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, cmd

I have a windows service application where I want to serve out a single html page to display simple runtime information for the service. I found the utility [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner) which allows me to combine my web files into a single html file, which is easy to serve up via self hosted web api running in the windows service.

I would like to auto run the script to build this single html file, so I put the command line into a .bat/.cmd file and then call this from **Visual Studio 2015** post build event. The source html file has a couple of references to scripts and css, eg

```
<head>
  <link href="lib\css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="lib\js\jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="_default.js"></script>
</head>
```

The contents of the .cmd (or .bat) file are as follows

```
 inliner.cmd -vs _default.html > default.html
```

When I run the above tried from the command prompt it works fine, but when I try and run the .bat file I get the following error..

```
'´╗┐inliner.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is there a way to run such a node command from a Visual Studio post build command, either via a batch/cmd file or otherwise? I did try straight from the Post command, rather than the .cmd file, but would still not get it to work correctly (though I could get it to produce the output html file, but it was always empty)

Thanks in advance for any pointers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.bat` file has a UTF-8 [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the start of it.

The three extra characters in your error message that precede `inliner.cmd` are the three characters that make up a UTF-8 byte order mark in [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

Try removing the byte-order mark from the file.

Comment: thanks, that was the problem! (I thought it was just some rubbish in the error message). The ,bat now works fine. It will now run from Visual Studio, but I still get no output from the inliner, but that is for another question.

Comment: Follow on question [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856916/running-the-node-utility-inliner-from-visual-studio)