# Running the node utility inliner from Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This follows on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840131/how-to-run-a-node-utility-in-a-cmd-or-bat-file) question.

I have a windows service application where I want to serve out a single html page to display simple runtime information for the service. I found the utility inliner which allows me to combine my web files into a single html file, which is easy to serve up via self hosted web api running in the windows service.

I would like to auto run the script to build this single html file, so I put the command line into a .bat/.cmd file and then call this from Visual Studio 2015 post build event. The source html file has a couple of references to scripts and css, eg

```
<head>
  <link href="lib\css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="lib\js\jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="_default.js"></script>
</head>
```

The contents of the .cmd (or .bat) file are as follows

```
echo %1
cd %1
dir .
where inliner
inliner -vs _default.html > default.html
```

In the  Visual Studio post build, I have have

```
call "$(ProjectDir)\WebAdminPanel\build.bat" "$(ProjectDir)\WebAdminPanel"
```

The `echo` and `dir.` are just debug output so I could see the directory was correctly changed (I thought this may be the issue)

The batch file (that now works when I run it manually), does run, but I still get an empty output file.

The `-v` flag should make the utility run verbose, but I do not see any output from in the Visual Studio output window; perhaps this would help to see what is going wrong. I am suspected perhaps it is not finding the includes, but not sure.

Is there anyone familiar with this utility and perhaps know why it fails when I run it as a Visual Studio post build task?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**(EDIT)**

In the visual studio output window I see

```
1> Directory of H:\dev\myapp\WebAdminPage
1>
1>  11/03/2016  03:10 PM    <DIR>          .
1>  11/03/2016  03:10 PM    <DIR>          ..
1>  11/03/2016  03:10 PM                79 build.bat
1>  11/03/2016  03:09 PM               182 default.html
1>  07/03/2016  12:41 PM    <DIR>          lib
1>  10/03/2016  11:12 PM             2,025 _default.html
1>  10/03/2016  11:06 PM             2,412 _default.js
1>                 4 File(s)          4,698 bytes
1>                 3 Dir(s)  1,376,883,204,096 bytes free
1>  C:\Users\peterc\AppData\Roaming\npm\inliner
1>  C:\Users\peterc\AppData\Roaming\npm\inliner.cmd
```

Comment: Do you see the results of the `echo` and `dir .` lines anywhere in Visual Studio, e.g. in the Output window?  If so, try adding `where inliner` above your call to `inliner` - perhaps there is an issue with the `PATH` that the `.bat` file is ending up running with?

Comment: Yes I see output. I've added to the question (as didn't have space here in the comment). The path to liner is correct, as are the dir contents it is reporting

Comment: Thanks for editing your question and including the output.  I have to admit I've never used inliner myself - I just wanted to be sure that the inliner script was being found.  Good luck, I hope someone can help you with this.